# TLS version on Http trace

Tags: http, ssl, tls1.2

I'm trying to understang which TLS version is used based on this logs (http trace)

*System.Net Information: 0 : [2544] SecureChannel#49129953::.AcquireClientCredentials, new SecureCredential() (flags=(ValidateManual, NoDefaultCred, SendAuxRecord), m_ProtocolFlags=(Ssl3Client, Tls10Client), m_EncryptionPolicy=RequireEncryption)
Algorithm: RSA
Length: 2048
Key Blob: 30 82 01 0a 02 82 01 01 00 b8 de 6a 2c a0 05 1d c1 2e 54 2d de 74 40 a6 83 2b 81 25 29 8d c1 2b e1 4d 4b 63 bd 7f c0 75 fe 15 eb 6b a6 2f 3c 65 d6 7a 55 dc 68 07 1c 6c 2e 8c cd d5 01 74 9f ca ca bb 5e b0 6d 9a 44 d1 1c 74 11 ca 4f 44 fa 59 59 22 f5 f9 c2 00 21 d6 1d a3 09 5a 0e fe da b7 ea d2 c8 55 51 c7 53 90 d1 b9 bf 2c 98 49 75 82 30 ....
System.Net Information: 0 : [2544] SecureChannel#49129953 - Remote certificate was verified as valid by the user.
System.Net Information: 0 : [2544] ProcessAuthentication(Protocol=Tls, Cipher=Aes128 128 bit strength, Hash=Sha1 160 bit strength, Key Exchange=RsaKeyX 2048 bit strength).*

Any idea? If you need more log let me know.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> ... m_ProtocolFlags=(Ssl3Client, Tls10Client) 
> ... ProcessAuthentication(Protocol=Tls
> ```

Based on this it should be TLS 1.0. For other versions like TLS 1.2 there is probably something like `Protocol=Tls12` instead